# openssl command encrypt data does not match EVP_aes_128_cbc

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl

I tried the following C implementation of Openssl EVP function for AES-128-CBC encryption but the results I am getting are incorrect compared to the command line OpenSSL result.

I referenced the code on the site below.

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

C code implementation of AES-128-CBC:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

void handleErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;
    int ciphertext_len;

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}

int main (void)
{
    /* A 128 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"A[u@AD22ZAWm/3=E";

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"0";

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext =
        (unsigned char *)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    /*
     * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
     * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
     * algorithm and mode.
     */
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encrypt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                              ciphertext);

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the decrypted text */
    printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Ciphertext is:
0000 - 4f 21 68 b5 e9 90 b8 82-71 f2 d2 cd 60 2e fd f1   O!h.....q...`...
0010 - 48 10 d0 e4 f2 58 86 96-22 fa a5 d2 b6 9a 66 87   H....X..".....f.
0020 - e8 e6 bd 9e 73 ad 1e 0e-ec 0a f0 8b 11 83 9d 04   ....s...........
Decrypted text is:
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

OpenSSL command line:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc -K 415b7540414432325a41576d2f333d45 -iv 30000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd

Updated WRT suggestion : 
echo -n "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc -K 415b7540414432325a41576d2f333d45 -iv 30 | xxd
```

OpenSSL Output:

```
00000000: 29d1 cf44 9246 fd7c 48a9 2261 afc1 6b34  )..D.F.|H."a..k4
00000010: ca5c c44d eddd 27a0 d64d 9679 81e4 fcb1  .\.M..'..M.y....
00000020: 9f10 0e47 ef73 37fa 5aa8 1a85 ec70 05c6  ...G.s7.Z....p..
```

Why are the output results different ( key and iv are both in hex) ?
I understand that the usage of iv "0" isnt recommended.

But if the iv is "0" what should be the hex value considered to match the encryption in command line.

PS : changing IV in code isnt an option for me :(

Comment: You are using different IVs. If in the C code `unsigned char iv[] = {0x30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` is used, the ciphertexts are identical, except for the last block. The difference in the last block is because `echo` adds a newline at the end, so this must either be avoided (`-n`) or a newline must be added to the plaintext in the C code.

Comment: @Topaco i have changed my iv in command to 30 since changing iv in c code isnt an option but still i see the difference and i have taken care of new line too but no use so far

Comment: Just output your IV: `BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char*)iv, 16);`. Then you will find that the first byte is 0x30 and the subsequent bytes are random values as they are in memory (this is why I get a different ciphertext on my machine than you do). For the ciphertexts to be identical, the IVs must be identical. Thus, you have the following possibilities: Option 1: Use a fully defined IV in the C/C++ code (like in my previous comment). Option 2: Use your indeterminate IV, output it and apply it in the OpenSSL command.